# How to add the class 'wc-enhanced-select' to custom select field on checkout page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have created a custom select field using woocommerce_form_field on the checkout page. How do I make select field to be same as the ones we have in the WooCoommerce settings.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Always try to include relevant code so community can provide specific answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Assuming you are after the looks and feel of WooCommerce Select inputs.*

You need to add custom JavaScript for this. WooCommerce uses SelectWoo, a more accessible fork of Select2 JavaScript library for those fancy select inputs.

```
$('selector-for-your-select').selectWoo();
```

While `selectWoo` is by default available in `wp-admin`, on the [front-end](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/96b9ebae14fcca11196aaf5a571056e80a424b4c/includes/class-wc-frontend-scripts.php#L357) it is enqueued only on cart, checkout, and my-account pages.

If you want to use it on other pages then you need to `enqueue` it for them. Using `wp_enqueue('selectWoo');` or as a dependency to your front-end css/js `wp_enqueue` statement in your plugin, theme, or theme's functions.php.

To learn more about it visit:

- [selectWoo – An accessible replacement for select2](https://woocommerce.wordpress.com/2017/08/08/selectwoo-an-accessible-replacement-for-select2/)
- [Basic Usage](https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage)
- [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/woocommerce/selectWoo/)
- WooCommerce Front-end Assets - `woocommerce/includes/class-wc-frontend-scripts.php`
- WooCommerce Admin Assets - `woocommerce/includes/admin/class-wc-admin-assets.php`

Comment: Note that just adding the `wc-enhanced-select` class to the select element only works in wp-admin (`wc-enhanced-select.js` is an admin asset). That class is essentially just a helper class which is targeted with `.selectWoo()` on WC admin page loads.

Comment: @EvanMattson selectWoo() is [available](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/96b9ebae14fcca11196aaf5a571056e80a424b4c/includes/class-wc-frontend-scripts.php#L358) by default on frontend WooCommerce pages like cart, checkout, and my account.

Comment: Correct. I was not saying that `selectWoo` is not available on the front, but making a general note for others about the scope of the built-in support for the `.wc-enhanced-select` class which is what led me here in the first place.

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect the availability from admin and front-end. On the other hand, my solution doesn't expect `wc-enhanced-select` class but relies on developer to use a custom class and init the `selectWoo` on their own.